# Submit a Paper in a Journal with Email Address

Tags: paper-submission

I want to submit a paper in the following springer journal

[Applicable Algebra in Engineering, Communication and Computing](https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical%2Bcomputer%2Bscience/journal/200)

In its page, I could not find its editorial manager to submit my paper. Just there is the following email adress *aaecc@lix.polytechnique.fr*.
When I search the mentioned email address in google, the results of google results that there is no this email address.

**My question:** How to submit may paper in this springer journal and what is the standard way and expressions to email to that email address.

I greatly appreciate your assistance on my question.

Comment: Why are you searching for the email address exactly? All you're testing is if it's been published in clear text on a page indexed by Google. Case in point, I have several email addresses, some of which Google don't find, yet they all work.

Comment: @Anyon you know, I just submit my paper with editorial manager s and just for check the email address I search it.Is it Possible to ask you to help me that what sentences I should write in the body of email for submitting my paper. Thanks again

Comment: Just follow the link they give to complete a submission : https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical%2Bcomputer%2Bscience/journal/200

Comment: At least we have definitive proof that, as of today, Google does not know everything...

Comment: @SolarMike: The "Submit Online" button is a `mailto:` link...

Comment: @NateEldredge but does it work....

Comment: @John Custer: "*At least we have definitive proof that, as of today, Google does not know everything*" --- Perhaps more accurate is "does not reveal everything", which we probably knew well before today.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's a little odd that a Springer journal would ask for submissions by email, since they obviously have editorial manager software available, there's not really anything wrong with it.  Maybe the managing editor simply prefers to work that way.  It's also possible that the journal moved to Springer relatively recently, and is still using their previously established workflow.

As a check that this address is correct, note that `polytechnique.fr` is the École Polytechnique, which is the affiliation of the journal's managing editor-in-chief, Marc Giusti.  Again, it's not unusual for a journal manager to have their university set up an email account to receive journal submissions.  The fact that the address doesn't appear in Google means nothing, as noted in comments.

So just send an email to that address with your manuscript attached as PDF.  You can keep the subject and body very simple.  I would use a subject like "Submission to AAECC" and a body like:

> Dear editors:
>
> I would like to submit the attached manuscript for possible publication in AAECC.
>
> Thank you for your consideration, and for your work in editing this journal.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Author Name

You ought to receive a reply by email within a few days, acknowledging your submission and explaining whether there's anything further you need to do.